# Save Active Google Sheet as excel .XLSX to local computer or save to specific folder on OneDrive directly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I need to save one of the sheets as excel format with a specfic filename with today's date, preferably with a click of a button, and then download to local computer or save directly in specfic folder on OneDrive.

What I have now is basicly code I found that saves it to my private Google Drive root, but that does not help me, since I have users that need to download the .XLSX to their computer or save it to our company folder on OneDrive. One option is to be able to save it to a specific folder on Google Drive and then share this folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a `GET` request changing a little bit of the URL.

You can use as an example this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) explaining all the options.

Basically if your `id` is `<your-sheet-id>` do a request with the following format.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<your-sheet-id>/export?format=xlsx
```

You can test it with your browser. And it should download you the exported file right away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually tried this one. It works good, except I need it to change the name of the file when exporting. Is this possible? Instead of the format of the file like this "My spreadsheet - sheet1.xlsx" I need it to save with this name that changes depending on today's date "List of items YYYY-MM-DD.xlsx".

XLSX or PDF, either of these formats are fine.

Comment: How (from where) are you downloading the file? Maybe you could change the name before/after? You could create a trigger on Apps Script to update the name of the file daily, or to make a copy. I am not finding any parameter to change the name of the file on exporting.